# deepwater on a powerpc

Tags: r, h2o

I have installed `h2o_3.13.0.tar.gz` on `R 3.4.1` on a `ppc64le` box with 4 Tesla P100s running `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS`.  It has Cuda v8.0.61 (I am not sure how to check for cuDNN).

When I run the example in the deep-water booklet, in this step

```
model <- h2o.deepwater(x=features, y=target, ... nfolds=5, gpu=TRUE, seed=1234)
```

I get the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize the native Deep Learning backend: /tmp/libmxnet.so: /tmp/libmxnet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (Possible cause: can't load AMD 64-bit .so on a Power PC 64-bit platform)
```

While the file is there, when I run ldd on it, I get `not a dynamic executable`.

Does this mean that I need to compile mxnet for this architecture or am I missing something else?  Then I set `gpu=FALSE` in the same function.  I now get the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize the native Deep Learning backend: Could not initialize class deepwater.backends.mxnet.MXNetBackend$MXNetLoader
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We currently don't support the PowerPC architecture. You're getting this error because you try to run Intel x86-64 code and that does not work on ppc64.

Please see https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater to see what the requirements are for the code, and different ways of using it.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Would h2o.xgboost with GPU=TRUE not work either on this arch.  That is part of code h2o lib and not the deepwater bits.

Comment: No that does not work since TensorFlow and MXNet have been compiled for x86-64 and is included inside. For CPU-only, you have to use the version that is built for cpu only. There are downloads for this and we also have a cpu only docker image available, that's the easiest thing to use.